# Installing PCIE card - .exe windows driver file into Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 20.04, windows, pcie

I'm a newbie and I'm in the process of learning. I have a .exe file in windows which installs the drivers needed for NETNOW DH382 PCIE card, I want to install the same drivers or similar drivers(which I was not able to find) into Ubuntu to make the card work. Is there any way to overcome this problem without having to reconfigure the Ubuntu kernel.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Ubuntu, and see if the card works in Linux? If not, it might be a good idea to research hardware, and buy hardware that are compatible. Drivers are generally not needed in Linux if you stick to well-known hardware.

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `lspci -nnk` Pick out the new PCI card and next edit your question to include the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Serial or Parallel ports, integrated or in add-on cards **need NO user installable drivers in desktop Linux since DECADES ago!**